# Check perrmision (gps) need stop function

Tags: android, android-gps

I need set gps in my Android application. But funcion requestLocationUpdates required check perrmision in this way:

```
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

If i remove return (from if) app crash. If i put return function requestLocationUpdates will not be called!

How fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You must not call *requestLocationUpdates* just after *requestPermissions*.

*requestPermissions* is an asynchronous call, "this" (your activity) is your listener

You have to implement in your activity:

```
 @Override
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
      //check if all the grantResult are equal to PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
 }
```

In that fonction check if the permission is accepted and if TRUE, then call your requestLocationUpdates.

Comment: I have onRequestPermissionResult in my code. But if i move .requestLocationUpdates to section PERMISSION_GRANTED. Again i obtain error check perrmision ;/

Comment: You can't make any mistake if you follow the documentation carefully : http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html